# loading Hierarchy in NSMutableData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there Hierarchy system in NSMutableData? If so, how do i load information in a hierarchy manner?
Example

```
//Create path to saving location
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSMutableData *gameData;
NSKeyedUnarchiver *decoder;
NSString *documentPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tierSave.dat"];
gameData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:documentPath];
//end

//start loading
    for(NSArray* firstData in gameData){

    decoder = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:gameData];

    int level1 = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:level1];
    }
//end
```

However in for(NSArray* firstData in gameData), the compiler tells me that gameData will not respond to count because it is a NSMutableData instead of NSMutableArray etc, How do i exactly re-implement the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving:

- Create a NSArray with your multiple NSData
- Use NSKeyedArchiver to make a NSData from your NSArray

Loading:

- Load a NSData from file
- Use NSKeyedUnarchiver to extract the NSArray
- Loop your NSArray

In code:
    NSData *data0 = [NSData data]; // Data 1
    NSData *data1 = [NSData data]; // Data 2

```
/////////// SAVE
// now make a array
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:data0, data1, nil];

// now archive the data
NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
// archivedData contains now a binary plist with your archived array including your NSData objects

[archivedData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];



/////// LOAD
NSData *archivedDataFromFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSArray *newArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedDataFromFile];

NSData *dataLoaded0 = [newArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Do you mind to be a little more specific? I am a quite new to this. Thanks

Comment: It's simple and clear, i am going to try it out. Thanks for your time! have a good day